# Symfony - botched project with cache:clear

Tags: symfony, caching

I have a little problem concerning `cache:clear` following a tutorial that told me if I have an error while running the command, I could delete the `dev` folder by hand in `var/cache/dev` 
So when running the command to clear the cache, I got this error:

```
[Symfony\Component\Filesystem\Exception\IOException]                                  
  Failed to remove file "/var/www/html/Symfony/var/cache/de~/profiler/26/75/2d7526":
```

So as the error appeared I decided to delete the dev folder in `/var/dev`

But then I couldn't go anymore on my browser checking if everything worked fine. This error came up.

```
RuntimeException in ClassCollectionLoader.php line 309: Failed to write cache file "/var/www/html/Symfony/var/cache/dev/classes.php".
```

I have no idea as how to make it work again.
My `dev` and `prod` cache folders are back in my `cache folder` as expected, but that doesn't do anything. It won't work anymore.

So I'm a bit desperate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you setup correctly the file permissions for the `var` folder?

See this link: http://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/file_permissions.html

Comment: Yes i did that at the beginning of the project with chmod 777 -R var and it worked fine until I deleted the cache clear folder by hand

Comment: What are you using to clear the cache? Maybe this: `php app/console cache:clear --env=prod` Also what OS do you have and web server?

Comment: I used php bin/console cache:clear. but I got the error specified in the ticket I opened. So the tutorial I was following told me I could delete by hand the dev folder in /var/cache. And after i did that, nothing worked anymore. I'm trying to see about the rights. And after doing chmod 777, my page changed, but still get an error.

Comment: Please delete the **entire** var/cache and var/logs folder and try again.

Comment: Okay, I did the reset of my rights, it worked.... but once I did again a cache:clear command I get the same error line 309 specified in my ticket... I will try to delete the entire var/cache as you recommend me.

Comment: can't delete the whole cache folder, I get this error: java.io.IOException: Cannot delete '/var/www/html/Symfony/var/cache'

Comment: Why are you getting a Java IO error??? Is there something you **haven't** told us about your environment?

Comment: my prod folder is locked. I think it is this one that cause the problem. I tried again by putting chmod and my page opened again. i did then bin/console cache:clear --env=prod and it cleared my cache, and my page was back on track. Can't understand it :/

Comment: Thank you by the way to have good tracked me on the rights. Without it I wouldn't have guessed it.